# Can you do GPGPU on integrated graphics like Intel HD 630 on Core i3?

Tags: cuda

The Core i3 says it has "integrated graphics" with Intel 630.

Does this mean it is like a mini GPU?

In which case can use things like CUDA to speed up C sharp programs?

Is there much software that takes advantage of integrated graphics? Like does photoshop access the integrated graphics?

Answer (score 2):

CUDA is only available on nvidia cards.

The open technology is OpenCL: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL

Another alternative is to use Compute Shaders. DirectX, OpenGL, and Vulkan all support compute shaders

Comment: I would remove the phrase "must be" and replace it with "is usually". There are other systems such as Metal Compute and I would assume some equivalent Direct X mechanism. I believe that Vulkan also has a compute engine.

Comment: That's true but computer shaders use the GPU in graphics mode, the question was about General Purpose, where the GPU is used in computing mode. They are two different pipelines and depending on the purpose of the application, one or the other will normally be used, switching between them is "expensive" computationally. Good point anyway ;)